# verification of compliance, not working properly

Tags: regex, flash

my source

`var reg:RegExp = /[0-9A-Za-z]/;`

`reg.test("fsfm32423sda");` - now is true

`reg.test("fsfm32423sda!!!___---");`  - now is true - but must be false because the string contains characters `"!_-"` - they are not included in "var reg"

how to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only testing one character as you have no quantifier. Try:

```
var reg:RegExp = /^[0-9A-Za-z]+$/;
```

The caret `^` marks the beginning of the string, the dollar `$` the end.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this: `[0-9A-Za-z]` is that it will match any string which might have letters or digits. However, it does not specify anything else. Changing it to `^[0-9A-Za-z]+$` should solve your issue.

What the `^` and `$` anchors do is that they instruct the regex engine to start and stop matching at the beginning and end of the string respectively. This will make sure that your string is solely composed of one or more letters and/or digits.